# Как в CSS задать градиент для border?

Tags: css

Всем привет!
Вот к примеру для для фона градиента надо писать:

```
background: linear-gradient(to left, #FFF, #CACACA);
```

А как задать градиент к примеру для border-left: ?

Comment: погуглил за вас, Решение есть [тут][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717127/css3-gradient-borders

Answer (score 2):

Функции градиента работают как изображения, поэтому их надо применять там, где требуется подставить изображения. Для рамки это будет `border-image`, как-то так:

```css
div {
  border-width: 10px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-image: linear-gradient(to left, #ff0000, #0000ff) 0 0 0 100%;
}
```

```html
<div>for ru.stackoverflow</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
.b-gradient{
  font-size: 15px;
  max-width: 300px;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 25px auto;
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 15px;
}
.b-gradient:before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 8px; 
}
.b-gradient-vertical:before{
  background: rgb(255,0,0); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#0000ff',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.b-gradient-gorizontal:before{ 
background: rgb(255,0,0); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#0000ff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
}
.b-gradient-radial:before{
 background: rgb(255,0,0); /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 50%, rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* FF3.6-15 */
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* Chrome10-25,Safari5.1-6 */
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(255,0,0,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 50%,rgba(0,0,255,1) 100%); /* W3C, IE10+, FF16+, Chrome26+, Opera12+, Safari7+ */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff0000', endColorstr='#0000ff',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 fallback on horizontal gradient */
}
```

```html
<div class="b-gradient b-gradient-vertical">
А как задать градиент к примеру для border-left: ?
  А как задать градиент к примеру для border-left: ?
</div>
<div class="b-gradient b-gradient-gorizontal">
А как задать градиент к примеру для border-left: ?
  А как задать градиент к примеру для border-left: ?
</div>
<div class="b-gradient b-gradient-radial">
А как задать градиент к примеру для border-left: ?
  А как задать градиент к примеру для border-left: ?
</div>
```